# Add a new line in r

Tags: r, insert, line

I have a huge csv file containing text which I want to break in to line 80 characters long.
The small fragment of the file is as follows:

> `ATTTATGAAGGAGAGGGGTCAGGGTTGATTCGGGAGGATCCTATTGGTGCGGGGGCTTTGTATGATTATGGGCGTTGATTAGTAGTAGTTACTGGTTGAACATTGTTTGTTGGTGTATATATTGTAATTGAGATTGCTCGGGGGAATAGGATGATGTATGCTTTGTTTCTGTTGAGTGTGGGTTTAGTAATGGGGTTTGTGGGGTTTTCTTCTAAGCCTTCTCCTATTTATGGGGGTTTAGTATTGATTGTTAGCGGTGTGGTCGGGTGTGTTATTATTCTGAATTTTGGGGGAGGTTATNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCTATTCCTCATCACCCAACTAAAAATATTAAACACAAACTACCACCTACCTCCCTCACCAAAGCCCATAAAAATAAAAAATTATAACAAACCCTGAGAACCAAAATGAACGAAAATCTGTTCGCTTCATTCATTGCCCCCACAATCCTAGATGCCCCAACTAAATACTACCGTATGGCCCACCATAATTACCCCCATACTCCTTACACTATTCCTCATCACCCAACTAAAAATATTAAACACAAACTACCACCTACCTCCCTCACCAAAGCCCATAAAAATAAAAAATTATAACAAACCCNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCTAACCTGACTAGAAAAGCTATTACCTAAAACAATTTCACAGCACCAAATCTCCACCTCCATCATCACCTCAACCCAAAAAGGCATAATTAAACTTTACTTCCTCTCTTTCTTCTTCCCACTCATCCTAACCCTACTCCTAATCACATAAATAACCATGCACACTACTATAACCACCCTAACCCTGACTTCCCTAATTCCCCCCATCCTTACCACCCTCGTTAACCCTAACAAAAAAAACTCATACCCCCATTATGTAAAATCCATTGTCGCATCCACCTTTATTATCAGTCTCTTCCCCNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNATCTAGAAATTGCCCTCCTTTTACCCCTACCATGAGCCCTACAAACAACTAACCTGCCACTAATAGTTATGTCATCCCTCTTATTAATCATCATCCTAGCCCTAAGTCTGGCCTATGAGTGACTACAAAAAGGATTAGACTGAACCGAATATAAACTTCGCCTTAATTTTAATAATCAACACCCTCCTAGCCTTACTACTAATAATTATTACATTTTGACTACCACAACTCAACGGCTAC`

How do I do this in R?

Comment: If you're on linux or OS X you can do a `fold -w 80 FILENAME > newfile.txt` from a terminal/shell which will wrap any file at 80 chars. A side note that you really don't have a CSV file if it's just a long string of gene sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 lines <- readLines('bigline.txt') 
 v1 <- strsplit(lines,'(?<=[A-Z]{80})', perl=TRUE)[[1]]

  nchar(v1)
 #[1] 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 10

 identical(v1[1], substr(lines,1,80))
 #[1] TRUE
 identical(v1[2], substr(lines,81,160))
 #[1] TRUE
```